Creating a dynamic range in excel using a variable starting cell
I am trying to create dynamic ranges to be used for excel charts.
I have the following range:
=OFFSET(O7,0,0,1,COUNTA($O$5:$X$5))
cell o7 is expected to change.
I have created the following formula to find the starting cell
=CELL("ADDRESS",INDEX(N6:N14,MATCH("AC",N6:N14,0)))
as result, it gives $n$7
however, when I tried to blend the second one in the first one, I receive an error.
My question is, starting from the first range (offset), how can I make the cell o7 variable possibly using an index formula?
Than you

How about: =INDEX(O6:X14,MATCH("AC",N6:N14,0),SEQUENCE(,COUNTA($O$5:$X$5))?

It works!!!
THANK YOU SCOTT, I spent at least 1 hr on this before giving up.
May I ask you to explain in few words how it works? I understand the index and match, however I am not familiar with the sequence.
Thanks again for your much appreciated help

All the Sequence is doing is creating an array of 1,2,3,... to the number of columns that have a value in it.  If O through X always has values and you always want to return all the columns then just put 0 in place of the whole SEQUENCE() function.  The third criterion of INDEX is the column(s).  0 returns them all, while an array of numbers will return those columns.
